# Fedor's lazy load for gallery and modify

Tags: android

I had try Fedor's lazy load for gallery like https://github.com/thest1/LazyList.
And in GalleryAdapter getView() as below:

```
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(PhotoPath[position], iv);
```

I want each picture contains which loading drawable to zoom in or zoom out to fix the screen size.
Where should I modify?

Comment: Could you be more clearer? So you want to add a zoom feature to the gallery??

Comment: I wan show one picture in full screen. But now if picture loading, it shows the drawable in res. But the size is not fix to screen, and show several pictures in screen at one time.

Comment: But I didn't know where to modify about this require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your ImageView layout to FILL_PARENT:

```
iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: But why line iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); seems doesn't work.